# Use background images without knowing programming?

Tags: 7, media, theming

I'm trying to set up a site using Drupal 7, and have very little knowledge of the stuff under the hood.  If the answer is to edit some css, please give VERY simple instructions.

Is there a simple way to put background images in the Acquia Marina theme?

Or, are there similar looking themes that have this facility built in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should change the body background selector in the css file of the template, for example

```
body{ background: url("path to image");}
```

[More info how to use background css](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/background.php)

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer and the link.  I think I have to do some research on this css editing before I go any further.

To show how ignorant I am in this, does it matter where in the css template file pieces like this go?  Is there a specific section for specific commands?

Comment: It does not matter where within a CSS file you put particular CSS rules. In Fusion-based themes like Acquia Marina, we suggest that you use the local.css file, to keep your CSS customizations separate from the theme's CSS. You can learn more about that in the documentation here: http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/support/documentation/customizing-your-theme